# How to convert & insert string into List<int> at the same time?

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I want to get some data out of telerik grid view and  convert it's values(some cells) into `List<int>`  (and some not)

i just want insert it into the list

```
foreach (int item in _MyAmount)
{
     _MyAmount.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
     radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[item].Value.ToString();
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you define the steps you need to take, and the order in which you want to do them? Your sample code is a bit jumbled and unclear.

Comment: @stuartd i want to convert it first

Comment: `radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[item].Value.ToString();` does nothing.  And why is it wrapped in the foreach?

Comment: @MostafaBouzari what is the "it" you want to convert? The current cell's value? And so once you have converted it to an int you want to add it to an existing list?

Comment: @stuartd i want to get all of rows and convert some of them and yes after converting i want to add it to list i might need help on inserting it too

Comment: @NETscape i suppose that does the inserting pert i'm not sure about that

Comment: @MostafaBouzari so you don't want to add the value to the end of the list, you want to insert it instead? Can you give a bit more detail about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MostafaBouzari what you're doing sounds impossible.  You can convert to string and add it to a list of ints.  Please edit your question to clarify what you need.

Comment: @stuartd there is nothing in it and i want to insert the data which comes from a data grid view (telerik)

Comment: @NETscape no,i want to convert the string into int

Comment: So to confirm, you're going through each row in a data grid view (telerik), converting the value to int and then adding it to a list?

Comment: @sr28 yes,first i want to convert them then inserting them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your foreach loop is bit iffy. From what you've described you want to run through every row in the telerik gridview (presumably radGridView1?), convert it to int and then save it in _MyAmount.

If my assumptions are correct then you should use something like this:

```
foreach (var Row in radGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (var Cell in Row.Cells)
    {
        _MyAmount.Add((int) Cell.Value);
    }
}
```

This assumes there is more than 1 cell in each row. If not then you could shorten to:

```
foreach (var Row in radGridView1.Rows)
{
    _MyAmount.Add((int) Row.Cells[0].Value);
}
```

***UPDATE***

For a RadGrid try this:

```
foreach (var Row in radGridView1.Items)
{
    _MyAmount.Add((int) Row["UniqueName"].Text);
}
```

***UPDATE 2***

Seems a bit odd that it accepts 'Rows' as a collection on radGridView1 but then not '.Value' for the cell. I'm guessing a bit now, but what if you tried mixing the 2 like this:

```
foreach (var Row in radGridView1.Rows)
{
    _MyAmount.Add((int) Row["UniqueName"].Text);
}
```

Comment: there is more than just a cell in a row,but for each column  i want to add separately cause some of them needs converting

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - This will run through every row, not just 1. If that's not what you mean then I've misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - No problem. Please mark this as the answer if it's worked for you.

Comment: _MyAmount.Add((int) Row.Cells[0].Value); in the value part it gives a error [Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found......]

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - if it's a RadGrid then try my update.

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - so it doesn't think there's anything called 'Items'? Are you sure this is a telerik radgrid?

Comment: yes,its telerik it has this [radGridView1] i didn't  change the name though

Comment: for converting and inserting one column in all rows into my list youre Update 2 is enough ??

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - yes. The foreach loop goes through every row in radGridView1. The value in the column you want is converted to int using (int) and added to _MyAmount.

Comment: can you help me with this one too [Error 1 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo.this[Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewColumn]' is inaccessible due to its protection level]

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - that's not linked to this question. Best thing to do would be to create a new question and I will take a look. If this answer has worked for this question please mark it as the answer.

Comment: in this part  Row["UniqueName"] i should type the heading of my own column??